# Nokia 6.1 stuck in "Download mode"

Tags: fastboot, android-one, nokia-6.1

One day my Nokia 6.1 goes into "Download mode" and rebooting doesn't help.

Flashing TWRP doesn't work:

```
$ fastboot boot twrp-3.3.1-0-PL2.img 
downloading 'boot.img'...
OKAY [  1.235s]
booting...
FAILED (remote: unlock device to use this command)
finished. total time: 1.236s
```

Unlocking doesn't work:

```
$ fastboot oem unlock
...
FAILED (remote: Flashing Unlock is not allowed
)
finished. total time: 0.000s
$ fastboot flashing unlock
...
FAILED (remote: Flashing Unlock is not allowed
)
finished. total time: 0.000s
```

Repeatedly calling `fastboot continue` just prints a bunch of system info on my phone screen (e.g. `DEVICE STATE = locked`).

How do I recover the phone?

Answer (score 0):

## Factory reset

For some reason, my device was on slot b:

```
$ fastboot getvar current-slot
current-slot: b
finished. total time: 0.001s
```

After changing to slot a,

```
$ fastboot set_active a
Setting current slot to 'a'...
OKAY [  0.009s]
finished. total time: 0.010s
$ fastboot continue 
resuming boot...
OKAY [  0.319s]
finished. total time: 0.319s
```

I got a menu offering a factory reset, after which the phone booted into the OS.

Comment: ...then download the [Nokia Bootloader Unlocker app](https://www.nokia.com/en_int/phones/bootloaderunlocker.apk) and follow [Nokia's instrucitons](https://www.nokia.com/phones/en_int/bootloader) to unlock.